# Best practice? - JUnit Class per page vs Single JUnit Class for entire web application

Tags: java, selenium, testing, junit, automation

I would like to understand what is the best practice to execute `Selenium` tests in a multi-page web application.

Pages:

1. Home page
2. Product page
3. Checkout page

So my question comes down to:

1. Should I have a JUnit class per page (this is my current approach)
   OR
2. Should I have just one JUnit class (similar to Test Suite - never ever created one before) that tests all of the application's pages in one go. 
   Of course, I plan on having multiple methods (annotated with @Test) within it for testing each page functionality.

My current approach which is based on option #1, just before the execution of the test I launch the browser using `setUp()` method annotated with `@BeforeClass` and then close the browser  with `tearDown()` method annotated with `@AfterClass` respectively. My confusion with this approach is that if it's a best practice and the correct way to go about testing all these 3 pages since I am launching and closing the browser 3 times here.

Note: Using `Maven` for current project. I did some googling around and in most of the examples/articles that I see online people recommend using `mvn test` command to execute all the tests.

Please guide.

Comment: Ideally, you should use the Page Object Model to represent your pages and then test cases to represent stories or actions. [Geb](http://gebish.org) is tremendously useful here.

Comment: I am already using the Page Object Model here but the confusion is around the best practices on how to test an entire web application.